# Will family members get to visit each other if separated into different kingdoms in heaven?

Tags: lds, heaven, family, kingdom-of-heaven

I have been told by my LDS bishop not to fear losing family members forever. I know that the family is very important to Heavenly Father and his Son, but how important is it really?

Will we get to visit our families in heaven if we are separated into different kingdoms,  such as the Celestial, Terrestrial, and Telestial kingdoms? Will only people from the Celestial get to visit others, or could family members in the Telestial visit someone in the Celestial?

I have always had the fear of losing family because we won't be able to visit each other in heaven. I have also had the fear that I might be the person to be in one of the lower kingdoms.

I would like an answer based on LDS traditions and beliefs.

I would also like to consider this question as to how could I answer it based on LDS beliefs if someone else asked me about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main verses of scripture that apply to this are [D&C 76:86–88](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76.86-88?lang=eng#85), which is in the section of D&C 76 that discusses those in the telestial kingdom:

> 86 These [*those in the telestial kingdom*] are they who receive not of his fulness in the eternal world, but of the Holy Spirit **through the ministration of the terrestrial**;
>
> 87 **And the terrestrial through the ministration of the celestial**.
>
> 88 And also the telestial receive it of the administering of angels who are appointed to minister for them, or who are appointed to be ministering spirits for them; for they shall be heirs of salvation.

In other words, there will be ministration by those in the celestial kingdom to those in the terrestrial kingdom, and also by those in the terrestrial kingdom to those in the telestial kingdom. You can go down to visit people, but not up.

Comment: That is so helpful. Thank you for helping me find those scriptures.And what if I'm the one down below? How do I get rid of the fear of not being the one down below the Celestial?

Comment: @anonymous Live to qualify for the Celestial Kingdom.

Comment: What are the qualifications and limitations exactly? How far will God's mercy go?

Comment: That sounds like a whole new question. Feel free to [ask a new question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: My understanding was that in the Celestial kingdom, each person exalted receives their own planet. If I understand your answer, you can come down to earth to visit family, but they cannot come to you in your celestial kingdom on your planet. Is this correct? If so, what if two persons are exalted? Can they visit each other's planets?

Comment: @JamesShewey: That is not LDS doctrine. Though not an official site of the LDS church, I think this explains it pretty well: http://en.fairmormon.org/God_of_our_own_planet